# gcloud API hosting random response 500s

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, flask-restful

Running a flask rest API on google cloud which works differently depending on how exactly I call it.
Situation 1: I make each call manually/1 at a time and everything goes perfectly smoothly
Situation 2: I sleep in between each call for 2 seconds. In this case most of the calls work perfectly fine but one or two out of 15 fail with response 500.
Situation 3: I run all of the calls in a loop without sleeping. Every other call then fails with response 500.

The error logs show absolutely nothing and after excessive printing it seems like everything is working fine technically speaking. I am new to hosting on google cloud so could be missing something simple but I'm confused by the fact that if I make the API calls 1 at a time (with the exact same inputs) nothing fails.
(Please feel free to request more info, not entirely sure what I should be including here)

Comment: Can you share the response? Is it a server error from your flask app or from gcloud?

Comment: 500 means your code is crashing. Find where and you will know why. Otherwise, all we can do is speculate, guess and offer opinions. All of which are off-topic.

Comment: @thebadgateway <title>500 Server Error</title>
</head>
<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
<h1>Error: Server Error</h1>
<h2>The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.<p>Please try again in 30 seconds.</h2>

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to the resource problem.

If you host your API on Cloud Run, you can try to change the concurrency to 1. This will limit the amount of request per instance. You might wanna increase the RAM allocation per instance as well.

Have a look at the dashboard and see what the graph says.